# Problem in installing mysql in red hat?

Tags: linux

I am trying to install mysql in red hat  when I execute the command `rpm -ivh "package-name"` it is giving the following error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by MySQL-server-5.5.12-1.rhel5.i386<br>
        rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by MySQL-server-5.5.12-1.rhel5.i386
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are obviously not running RHEL 5. Install packages for the appropriate version of your distro.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dependancy. Apparently you need libpcap, so install it first:

```
yum install libpcap
```

Comment: what is the relationship between packet analyser and DB?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not have the package "glibc" installed.